# nav-bar hiding not working when setting overflow: auto in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So my website is set up like this:

```
<body>
   <nav></nav>
   <div id="background">
     <script></script>
     <script></script>
     <div id="content">
       <section id="about"></section>
       <section id="other"></section>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

with everything filled in with content and things. I wanted to make the background of this web page [this](https://codepen.io/Nazar_TheVis/pen/zqXMqP), but i was having trouble making the content show up on the background, and when it did to get the background to show on the entire page (the page is long so requires a vertical scroll). finally, I got it to work by setting it up like this:

```
<body>
   <div class="stars">
   <div class="twinkling">
   <div class="clouds">
   <nav></nav>
   <div id="background">
     <script></script>
     <script></script>
     <div id="content">
       <section id="about"></section>
       <section id="other"></section>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
   </div></div></div>
</body>
```

Now previously, before I started messing with this pen, my nav bar would hide when i scrolled down, and reappear as I scrolled up using javascript and a tranisiton

JS

```
(function(){
    var documentElem = $(document),
        nav = $('nav'),
        lastScrollTop = 0;
    documentElem.on('scroll', function(){
        var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        //down
        if(currentScrollTop> lastScrollTop) nav.addClass('hidden');
        //upper
        else nav.removeClass('hidden');
        lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    });
})();
```

CSS

```
            nav {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0;
                background-color: #7b7d7d;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 1.25rem 0;
                transition: all 0.5s ease;
            }
            nav.hidden {
                transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
            }
            nav ul li{
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: 3.75rem;
            }
            nav ul li:last-child{
                margin-right: 0;
            }
            nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #ecf0f1;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            }
```

By messing around and some research, I figured out how to extend the background to the bottom of the page using

```
overflow: auto;
```

in the provided css (from the pen link). Doing this, however, now makes the scrollbar stay on the screen, and basically acts as if the js wasnt there. I also noticed that with the overflow set as is, the scrollbar appears under the header, while the it appears over the header when everything is working as it should.

Again, my main goal was to just set that pen as the background, so if there is a more efficient way to do that please let me know, but the issue I am currently having is that my scrollbar no longer hides and transitions as it used to... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

My current code:

HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="stars">
        <div class="twinkling">
        <div class="clouds">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#title1">Title1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#title2">title2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#title3">title3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#title4">title4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="background">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <div id="content">
                <section id="title1">
                    <h1>Title1</h1>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id magna id est tincidunt semper. Duis neque nisi, bibendum ac metus a, hendrerit ullamcorper nisl. Cras sed nibh ipsum. Morbi justo sapien, convallis a pellentesque et, maximus at risus. Ut sollicitudin convallis faucibus. Etiam tincidunt dignissim convallis. Donec malesuada fringilla tortor sit amet imperdiet.

Donec vel malesuada leo. Sed molestie pharetra mi, sed feugiat nisi tempor a. Donec vitae tortor nibh. Morbi ac lorem sit amet diam lobortis pellentesque et quis lorem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque non luctus justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque varius elit a auctor. Vivamus vel auctor ipsum, viverra interdum lacus. Proin ullamcorper blandit magna, in dapibus mauris rutrum eget. Phasellus facilisis justo non libero sagittis, in tempus diam pellentesque. Donec varius nisl eu purus viverra, nec tristique tortor tristique. Vivamus varius commodo diam sed consequat.

Nulla convallis iaculis nunc, eu congue ante pellentesque non. Maecenas sagittis scelerisque eros, vel ullamcorper orci blandit ut. Nullam aliquet mattis nibh, vitae eleifend orci ultrices quis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam placerat nibh et enim venenatis sagittis. Ut erat metus, mollis sit amet tortor vitae, ultrices tristique nulla. Nam elementum tincidunt felis sed hendrerit. Nam ut purus nibh.

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id magna id est tincidunt semper. Duis neque nisi, bibendum ac metus a, hendrerit ullamcorper nisl. Cras sed nibh ipsum. Morbi justo sapien, convallis a pellentesque et, maximus at risus. Ut sollicitudin convallis faucibus. Etiam tincidunt dignissim convallis. Donec malesuada fringilla tortor sit amet imperdiet.

Donec vel malesuada leo. Sed molestie pharetra mi, sed feugiat nisi tempor a. Donec vitae tortor nibh. Morbi ac lorem sit amet diam lobortis pellentesque et quis lorem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque non luctus justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque varius elit a auctor. Vivamus vel auctor ipsum, viverra interdum lacus. Proin ullamcorper blandit magna, in dapibus mauris rutrum eget. Phasellus facilisis justo non libero sagittis, in tempus diam pellentesque. Donec varius nisl eu purus viverra, nec tristique tortor tristique. Vivamus varius commodo diam sed consequat.

Nulla convallis iaculis nunc, eu congue ante pellentesque non. Maecenas sagittis scelerisque eros, vel ullamcorper orci blandit ut. Nullam aliquet mattis nibh, vitae eleifend orci ultrices quis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam placerat nibh et enim venenatis sagittis. Ut erat metus, mollis sit amet tortor vitae, ultrices tristique nulla. Nam elementum tincidunt felis sed hendrerit. Nam ut purus nibh.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section id="title2">
                    <h1>title2</h1>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id magna id est tincidunt semper. Duis neque nisi, bibendum ac metus a, hendrerit ullamcorper nisl. Cras sed nibh ipsum. Morbi justo sapien, convallis a pellentesque et, maximus at risus. Ut sollicitudin convallis faucibus. Etiam tincidunt dignissim convallis. Donec malesuada fringilla tortor sit amet imperdiet.

Donec vel malesuada leo. Sed molestie pharetra mi, sed feugiat nisi tempor a. Donec vitae tortor nibh. Morbi ac lorem sit amet diam lobortis pellentesque et quis lorem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque non luctus justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque varius elit a auctor. Vivamus vel auctor ipsum, viverra interdum lacus. Proin ullamcorper blandit magna, in dapibus mauris rutrum eget. Phasellus facilisis justo non libero sagittis, in tempus diam pellentesque. Donec varius nisl eu purus viverra, nec tristique tortor tristique. Vivamus varius commodo diam sed consequat.

Nulla convallis iaculis nunc, eu congue ante pellentesque non. Maecenas sagittis scelerisque eros, vel ullamcorper orci blandit ut. Nullam aliquet mattis nibh, vitae eleifend orci ultrices quis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam placerat nibh et enim venenatis sagittis. Ut erat metus, mollis sit amet tortor vitae, ultrices tristique nulla. Nam elementum tincidunt felis sed hendrerit. Nam ut purus nibh.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section id="title3">
                    <h1>title3</h1>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id magna id est tincidunt semper. Duis neque nisi, bibendum ac metus a, hendrerit ullamcorper nisl. Cras sed nibh ipsum. Morbi justo sapien, convallis a pellentesque et, maximus at risus. Ut sollicitudin convallis faucibus. Etiam tincidunt dignissim convallis. Donec malesuada fringilla tortor sit amet imperdiet.

Donec vel malesuada leo. Sed molestie pharetra mi, sed feugiat nisi tempor a. Donec vitae tortor nibh. Morbi ac lorem sit amet diam lobortis pellentesque et quis lorem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque non luctus justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque varius elit a auctor. Vivamus vel auctor ipsum, viverra interdum lacus. Proin ullamcorper blandit magna, in dapibus mauris rutrum eget. Phasellus facilisis justo non libero sagittis, in tempus diam pellentesque. Donec varius nisl eu purus viverra, nec tristique tortor tristique. Vivamus varius commodo diam sed consequat.

Nulla convallis iaculis nunc, eu congue ante pellentesque non. Maecenas sagittis scelerisque eros, vel ullamcorper orci blandit ut. Nullam aliquet mattis nibh, vitae eleifend orci ultrices quis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam placerat nibh et enim venenatis sagittis. Ut erat metus, mollis sit amet tortor vitae, ultrices tristique nulla. Nam elementum tincidunt felis sed hendrerit. Nam ut purus nibh.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section id="title4">
                    <h1>title4</h1>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id magna id est tincidunt semper. Duis neque nisi, bibendum ac metus a, hendrerit ullamcorper nisl. Cras sed nibh ipsum. Morbi justo sapien, convallis a pellentesque et, maximus at risus. Ut sollicitudin convallis faucibus. Etiam tincidunt dignissim convallis. Donec malesuada fringilla tortor sit amet imperdiet.

Donec vel malesuada leo. Sed molestie pharetra mi, sed feugiat nisi tempor a. Donec vitae tortor nibh. Morbi ac lorem sit amet diam lobortis pellentesque et quis lorem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque non luctus justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque varius elit a auctor. Vivamus vel auctor ipsum, viverra interdum lacus. Proin ullamcorper blandit magna, in dapibus mauris rutrum eget. Phasellus facilisis justo non libero sagittis, in tempus diam pellentesque. Donec varius nisl eu purus viverra, nec tristique tortor tristique. Vivamus varius commodo diam sed consequat.

Nulla convallis iaculis nunc, eu congue ante pellentesque non. Maecenas sagittis scelerisque eros, vel ullamcorper orci blandit ut. Nullam aliquet mattis nibh, vitae eleifend orci ultrices quis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam placerat nibh et enim venenatis sagittis. Ut erat metus, mollis sit amet tortor vitae, ultrices tristique nulla. Nam elementum tincidunt felis sed hendrerit. Nam ut purus nibh.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section id="links">
                    <h1>Links</h1>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id magna id est tincidunt semper. Duis neque nisi, bibendum ac metus a, hendrerit ullamcorper nisl. Cras sed nibh ipsum. Morbi justo sapien, convallis a pellentesque et, maximus at risus. Ut sollicitudin convallis faucibus. Etiam tincidunt dignissim convallis. Donec malesuada fringilla tortor sit amet imperdiet.

Donec vel malesuada leo. Sed molestie pharetra mi, sed feugiat nisi tempor a. Donec vitae tortor nibh. Morbi ac lorem sit amet diam lobortis pellentesque et quis lorem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque non luctus justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque varius elit a auctor. Vivamus vel auctor ipsum, viverra interdum lacus. Proin ullamcorper blandit magna, in dapibus mauris rutrum eget. Phasellus facilisis justo non libero sagittis, in tempus diam pellentesque. Donec varius nisl eu purus viverra, nec tristique tortor tristique. Vivamus varius commodo diam sed consequat.

Nulla convallis iaculis nunc, eu congue ante pellentesque non. Maecenas sagittis scelerisque eros, vel ullamcorper orci blandit ut. Nullam aliquet mattis nibh, vitae eleifend orci ultrices quis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam placerat nibh et enim venenatis sagittis. Ut erat metus, mollis sit amet tortor vitae, ultrices tristique nulla. Nam elementum tincidunt felis sed hendrerit. Nam ut purus nibh.
                    </p>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <footer>

                </footer>
            </div>
        </div></div></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            nav {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0;
                background-color: #7b7d7d;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 1.25rem 0;
                transition: all 0.5s ease;
            }
            nav.hidden {
                transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
            }
            nav ul li{
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: 3.75rem;
            }
            nav ul li:last-child{
                margin-right: 0;
            }
            nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #ecf0f1;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            #background{
            }
            #content{
                padding-top: 4.25rem;
            }
            #title1{
                width: 50%;
                margin-left: 25%;
                padding-bottom: 1%;
                margin-bottom: 1%;
                border: 5px solid #d0d3d4;
                background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

                text-align: center;
            }
            #title1 h1{
                padding-bottom: 3%;
                padding-top: 1%;
            }
            #title1 p{
                padding-left: 10%;
                padding-right: 10%;
            }
            #title2{
                width: 50%;
                margin-left: 25%;
                padding-bottom: 1%;
                margin-bottom: 1%;
                border: 5px solid #d0d3d4;
                background: #283048;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

                text-align: center;
            }
            #title2 h1{
                padding-bottom: 3%;
                padding-top: 1%;
            }
            #title2 p{
                padding-left: 10%;
                padding-right: 10%;
            }
            #title3{
                width: 50%;
                margin-left: 25%;
                padding-bottom: 1%;
                margin-bottom: 1%;
                border: 5px solid #d0d3d4;
                background: #ffd89b;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #19547b, #ffd89b);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #19547b, #ffd89b); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

                text-align: center;
            }
            #title3 h1{
                padding-bottom: 3%;
                padding-top: 1%;
            }
            #title3 p{
                padding-left: 10%;
                padding-right: 10%;
            }
            #title4{
                width: 50%;
                margin-left: 25%;
                padding-bottom: 1%;
                margin-bottom: 1%;
                border: 5px solid #d0d3d4;
                background: #283c86;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #45a247, #283c86);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #45a247, #283c86); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */


                text-align: center;
            }
            #title4 h1{
                padding-bottom: 3%;
                padding-top: 1%;
            }
            #title4 p{
                padding-left: 10%;
                padding-right: 10%;
            }
            #links{
                width: 50%;
                margin-left: 25%;
                padding-bottom: 1%;
                margin-bottom: 1%;
                border: 5px solid #d0d3d4;
                background: #C33764;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #1D2671, #C33764);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #1D2671, #C33764); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

                text-align: center;
            }
            #links h1{
                padding-bottom: 3%;
                padding-top: 1%;
            }
            #links p{
                padding-left: 10%;
                padding-right: 10%;
            }
            #footer{
                clear: both;
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                bottom: 0;
                background-color: #7b7d7d;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 0.5rem 0;
            }
            #footer a{
                font-size: 12px;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #ecf0f1;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            }























            @keyframes move-twink-back {
                from {
                    background-position: 0 0;
                }
                to {
                    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
                }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
          from {
            background-position: 0 0;
          }
          to {
            background-position: -10000px 5000px;
          }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
          from {
            background-position: 0 0;
          }
          to {
            background-position: -10000px 5000px;
          }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
          from {
            background-position: 0 0;
          }
          to {
            background-position: -10000px 5000px;
          }
        }

        @keyframes move-clouds-back {
          from {
            background-position: 0 0;
          }
          to {
            background-position: 10000px 0;
          }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes move-clouds-back {
          from {
            background-position: 0 0;
          }
          to {
            background-position: 10000px 0;
          }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes move-clouds-back {
          from {
            background-position: 0 0;
          }
          to {
            background-position: 10000px 0;
          }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes move-clouds-back {
          from {
            background-position: 0;
          }
          to {
            background-position: 10000px 0;
          }
        }

        .stars,
        .twinkling,
        .clouds {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          overflow: auto; /*removing this makes the background not fit, but the scrollbar will work*/
          display: block;
        }

        .stars {
          background: #000 url(http://sylvaingarnot.fr/media/stars.png) repeat top center;
          z-index: 0;
        }

        .twinkling {
          background: transparent url(http://sylvaingarnot.fr/media/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
          z-index: 1;
          -moz-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
          -ms-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
          -o-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
          -webkit-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
          animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
        }

        .clouds {
          background: transparent url(http://sylvaingarnot.fr/media/clouds.png) repeat top center;
          z-index: 3;
          -moz-animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
          -ms-animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
          -o-animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
          -webkit-animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
          animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
        }
```

Javascript

```
(function(){
    var documentElem = $(document),
        nav = $('nav'),
        lastScrollTop = 0;
    documentElem.on('scroll', function(){
        var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        //down
        if(currentScrollTop> lastScrollTop) nav.addClass('hidden');
        //upper
        else nav.removeClass('hidden');
        lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    });
})();
```

Comment: can you replicate your current issue in above `codepen`?

Comment: I couldnt do it so I could send the link, so I just uploaded my code. If you meant does the issue happen in the codepen, yes it acts the same as it does on my browser

Comment: so do you want to show scrollbar or hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll?see this https://jsfiddle.net/91rvs3ag/

Comment: I want to have the nav bar showing, then when i scroll down the nav bar should fade away. Then when i scroll up, the nav bar should come back again. If you remove the line i pointed out in my css code, you can see the desired effect, while if you add that line back in you can see what i want the background to do. Although i do like how it looks without the scrollbar, i will play around with that when the nav bar works again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

change `var documentElem = $(document)` to `var documentElem = $('.clouds')`.When you set `overflow:auto` for `.stars,.twinkling,.clouds` these classes,you cann't get scrollTop() of document.so check scrollTop() for any of these classes.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/72jqtzq4/)

updated:

To avoid navbar covering scrollbar use this code

```
var newWidth=$('.clouds').innerWidth()-$('.clouds')[0].scrollWidth;

nav.css({ 'width': 'calc(100% - ' + newWidth+ 'px)' });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/72jqtzq4/1/)

Comment: Wow so that fixed most of my problem! A couple things... Could you explain why that works? Im new to js so i must not really get how that $(document) portion works. Also, when doing this, the navbar when showing covers the scrollbar, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Here $(document) doesn't work because it has no overflowing content.Its having same height as body as you set overflow:scroll for `.stars,.twinkling,.clouds` these classes.see my updated answer above

Comment: I am sorry for taking so long to reply! Unfortunately, the scrollbar is still covered even after implementing this.. I am using google chrome to test so far if that changes anything